# global operator new, private c-tor and friend

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
class A
{
    A() {}
    friend class B;
};

class B
{
public:
    void foo() {A* p=new A;};
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo();

    A* p = new A;

    return 0;
}
```

The function `foo()` passes compilation, however the line `A* p = new A;` does not. How can this be? `new` is a global operator, thus it cannot call the private constructor, so why doesn't the compiler complain about `foo()` as well?

Answer (score 3):

The operator new function does not call constructors. It just allocates the needed storage.

The constructor is called afterwards by compiler magic and is considered to be done by `foo` and `main` respectively.

Comment: He says exactly the same thing as the other answers. If you know what's right, why did you ask the question?

Comment: @eva Let me check: answerer: 170k rep, asker: 6 rep. Answerer: 134x [tag:c++] gold badge, [only guy to have](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1904/c11) a [tag:c++11] gold badge... Shall we say you may have _jumped to the wrong conclusion_?

Comment: Obviously I didn't know and still don't fully understand the answer to my question, however the reason that I thought @litb's answer is not full is that there is both a new keyword and an operator new and my question is exactly about the distinction between those in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The new expression consists on a call to `operator new` to allocate memory (does not call the constructor, no access required) and a call to the constructor. The call to the constructor is done in the context of the expression, which in this case is  `B::foo` that has access to the constructor.

Comment: Perhaps someone can quote the standard about this?

Comment: @dribeas - that makes sense, but then the following code should pass compilation as well: 
class A { protected: A() {} }; class B:public A { public: void foo() {A* p=new A;}; }; And it doesn't..

Comment: @eva i doubt the standards text would help you rather than confuse you even more

Comment: @litb: regarding the standard - perhaps, but can you explain the difference between calling from friend (when the c-tor is private) and from derived (when the c-tor is protected)?

Comment: @eva: That is a common misconception on the meaning of `protected`. The access specifier `protected` grants access to the member in `base` only within the `base` subobject in `derived`. That is, if you have a protected member `x` in `base`, and `derived` extends base, it has access to `this->x` (or `x` in any other `derived` object), but not `o.x` if `o` is not of type `derived` (say `base`, or `derived2` where `derived2` extends `base` but not `derived`)

Comment: Tnx @dribeas. It is still not clear, since we can have a Base member in Derived (if it's c-tor is protected, not if it is private). Perhaps it is too heavy for a comment - I might start a new topic.

Comment: @eva: No, you can construct your base, but not a base member: `class B { protected: B(){} }; struct D : B { B member; }` will fail to compile. You can construct your *base* but not a member of that type if the constructor is protected.

Answer (score 1):

A new-expression does two things:

- calls some overload of `operator new` to acquire some memory;
- constructs an object in that memory.

The construction happens in the context of the new-expression, not the call to `operator new`. Therefore, the constructor must be accessible in that context; so in your example, it is accessible in `B::foo` but not in `main`.

Comment: Like a lot of initial answers you misunderstand OPs Q.OPs Q is why `new`, a global free standing operator function is able to call private constructor of an class.The OP is under the *assumption* that `new` calls the constructor.

Comment: @Als: Oh yes, you're right. I must have stopped reading at "How can it be?"

Comment: If it is a context matter, why the following code doesn't pass compilation?

    class A
    {
    protected:
     A() {}
    };

    class B:public A
    {
    public:
     void foo() {A* p=new A;};
    };

Perhaps someone can quote the standard about this?

Comment: Sorry about the unformatted code, I have no idea why that doesn't work :(

Comment: Protected only grants access to the protected variables of your specific instance of the base class- not other instances.

Comment: @DeadMG - Tnx!
There is still something I don't understand about that -
it is possible to have an A member in B if A's c-tor is protected, so what will be the context of that c-tor run?

Comment: @eva: Yes, `B` can have members of type `A`. Static members are constructed in the context of the class itself (`B`), and non-static members in the context of the constructor (`B::B()`), and the `friend class B;` declaration makes all of `A`'s members accessible in both contexts.

Comment: @Mike - tnx, but the context of B's c-tor is not enough, since you cannot run "new A" from B's ctor...

Comment: @eva: I don't know what you mean; if it's a member of `B`, then it's initialised by the constructor of `B`, and you don't use `new` at all. If there's still something you don't understand, then you should ask a separate question about that - comments are meant for clarifying the answer, not discussing other topics.

Comment: Tnx @Mike, I will start a new question.